# Searching a string, replacing instances of a word with a copy of itself, surrounded by HTML tags

Tags: c#, .net, regex, string, replace

My problem is that I would like to parse through a large string, find all instances of a word in that string, and then insert  tags around it so that it will be highlighted when displayed in an ASP.Net MVC 4 View.  The problem with the code below is that if I search for a word and use a different case than what is in the paragraph, it will find it, but will replace it with whatever case I originally searched with.

For instance, in the paragraph below, there are two instances of the word "lectus".

- If I search for "**lectus**", it will find it and replace it with "**lectus**".  That's fine.
- However, if I search for "**LECTUS**", it will find the two instances of "lectus" and replace it with "**LECTUS**".

What I *would like* to do is have it match the word, insert the tags, but leave the original word like it is - don't change it, just find it and wrap text around it.  Is there a method or function that already supports this?  I can't seem to find one...all results point to case-insensitive string replacement, which is what I'm already using.

```
// I want to find all instances of the word "lectus".
string wordToFind = "lectus";

// This is the paragraph to search...
string paragraph = "Phasellus vitae elit maximus, egestas nibh id, pretium lacus. Aliquam ac lectus quis urna pharetra consectetur. Mauris neque est, tempor ac urna quis, fringilla congue diam. Curabitur dictum arcu vitae purus pretium consectetur. In rutrum lectus neque, eget maximus nunc commodo in.";

// This searches the paragraph and replaces all instances of wordToFind with itself, wrapped in <span> tags for highlighting.  
paragraph.text = Regex.Replace(paragraph.text, wordToFind, "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>" + wordToFind + "</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it by using [substitution symbol](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ewy2t5e0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) `$0`, which corresponds to the value captured by your regex:

```
paragraph.text = Regex.Replace(paragraph.text, wordToFind, "<span style='background-color: #FFFF00'>$0</span>", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/DCCVwA)

Comment: Oh I see.  I disregarded that since it said "includes the last substring matched by the capturing group that is identified by number, where number is a decimal value, in the replacement string.", and I wasn't working with decimal values.  I should have read more into it.  Thank you!